# (Sql Server) BEGIN TRANSACTION vs (Qt) QSqlDatabase.database().transaction()

Tags: sql-server, transactions, pyqt5

What is the difference in performance & reliance when using Sql Server's BEGIN TRANSACTION vs Qt's QSqlDatabase.database().transaction(), does both do the same thing? Which is prefered?

Example using Sql Server's Transaction:

```
_databaseConnection.connect()
q = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
q.prepare("""BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
                BEGIN TRY
                    INSERT INTO Entity(Name, UserName)
                    SELECT :Name AS Name, :UserName AS UserName;
                    DECLARE @lastInsertedID INT
                    SET @lastInsertedID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                    INSERT INTO MyEntity(Pk_MyEntityID)
                    SELECT @lastInsertedID;

                    SELECT @lastInsertedID;        --the result-set will return the last Inserted Id

                    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]
                END TRY

                BEGIN CATCH
                    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]
                END CATCH""")
q.bindValue(":Name", "MyName")
q.bindValue(":UserName", "MyUsername")
q.exec_()
print("Inserted using Sql Server Transaction")
```

Example using Qt's Transaction:

```
_databaseConnection.connect()
q = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
QtSql.QSqlDatabase.database().transaction()
q.prepare("""INSERT INTO Entity(Name, UserName)
                SELECT :Name AS Name, :Username AS UserName;
                DECLARE @lastInsertedID INT
                SET @lastInsertedID =  SCOPE_IDENTITY();

            INSERT INTO MyEntity(Pk_MyEntityID)
                SELECT @lastInsertedID;

            SELECT @lastInsertedID;    --the result-set will return the last Inserted Id""")
q.bindValue(":Name", "MyName")
q.bindValue(":Username", "MyUsername")
q.exec_()
QtSql.QSqlDatabase.database().commit()
print("Inserted using Qt Transaction")
```

Comment: With structured error handling, I suggest this `CATCH` block error handling pattern to ensure the transaction is rolled back and the error reported to the client app (your code will hide the error): `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]; THROW;`. Also avoid unneeded complexity by avoiding named transactions unless you are using savepoints.

Comment: If you have client-side transaction support, prefer it, because you avoid the tricky bits of T-SQL error handling and have the option to integrate it with other processing. You also avoid potentially interfering with other code that uses client-side transactions, because those are not aware of transactions you begin in T-SQL unless through special effort. If you're going to use server-side transactions, use them in stored procedures and other clearly isolated blocks of code, not custom queries.

Comment: Client side does seem like the easiest approach. Even with that small example I manged to hide possible errors as pointed out by Dan